# Merge with multiple columns by conditions

Tags: r, merge, data.table, mapping, data-manipulation

I want to merge my data by condition. I browsed many websites but did not find what I want.
I have two data here:

```
# dt1
ColA1   ColA2     ColB    ColC    ColD           Area
TA43    TI44      S2230   Amy     2014-08-08     USA
TA63    TI64      T1205   Andy    2014-01-01     CANADA
TA28    TI100     L1288   Peter   2014-01-08     EU
TA28    TI100     L2231   Roger   2014-01-08     EU
TA92    NA        A2206   Jean    2014-01-12     China
TA14    NA        E2240   Freda   2014-01-05     Japan
TA69    TI50      N1029   Tina    2014-01-05     Mexico

# dt2
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD           TYPE
TI64     T1205   Andy    2014-01-01     I
TI100    L1288   Peter   2014-01-08     I
TI100    L2231   Roger   2014-01-08     I
TA92     A2206   Jean    2014-01-12     A 
TA14     E2240   Freda   2014-01-05     R
TA69     N1029   Tina    2014-01-05     A
```

What I want is:

```
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD           TYPE   Area
TI64     T1205   Andy    2014-01-01     I      CANADA
TI100    L1288   Peter   2014-01-08     I      EU
TI100    L2231   Roger   2014-01-08     I      EU
TA92     A2206   Jean    2014-01-12     A      China
TA14     E2240   Freda   2014-01-05     R      Japan
TA69     N1029   Tina    2014-01-05     A      Mexico
```

I explain here:
I want to mapping `dt1` to `dt2` by ColA, ColB, ColC and ColD.
If column `TYPE` in `dt2` is **A** and **R**, then merge by `ColA` in `dt2` with `ColA1` in `dt1`.
If column `TYPE` in `dt2` is **I**, then merge by `ColA` in `dt2` with `ColA2` in `dt1`.

Any idea for `data.table` way?

Comment: you don't merge with ColD, and keep ColD from dt2 ? because cold is inconsistent for Jean

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper sorry for that. I edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the desired output with `dplyr`. You may also use `inner_join` or `right_join` depending on what you're trying to achieve:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt2 %>% mutate(merge_col = ifelse(TYPE == "I","ColA2","ColA1")) %>%
  left_join(dt1 %>% gather(merge_col,ColA,ColA1,ColA2))

# Joining, by = c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "merge_col")
# ColA  ColB  ColC       ColD TYPE merge_col   Area
# 1  TI64 T1205  Andy 2014-01-01    I     ColA2 CANADA
# 2 TI100 L1288 Peter 2014-01-08    I     ColA2     EU
# 3 TI100 L2231 Roger 2014-01-08    I     ColA2     EU
# 4  TA92 A2206  Jean 2014-01-12    A     ColA1  China
# 5  TA14 E2240 Freda 2014-01-05    R     ColA1  Japan
# 6  TA69 N1029  Tina 2014-01-05    A     ColA1 Mexico
```

**data.table**

with data.table you can try this, it's the exact translation:

```
merge(
  dt2[,merge_col := ifelse(dt2$TYPE == "I","ColA2","ColA1")],
  melt(dt1,id = c("ColB","ColC","ColD","Area"),measure=c("ColA1","ColA2"),"merge_col","ColA"),
  all.x = TRUE
)
```

adjust parameters `all.x` and `all.y` depending on the type of join you want

Comment: Is there a `data.table` way?

Comment: great. If i have many columns in `dt1`, how can i do so I don't need to type all columns names in `id= c()`

Comment: it seemes that `id = c()` not affect that? just add `all.y = TRUE` after `all.x`?

Comment: all.x and all.y don't influence which columns are taken. melt may have some default behavior that I don't understand, so if Area & B C D are enough to guarantee unicity maybe it works as is